# How to save field in response data in to CSV in Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am trying to save Jmeter response in CSV file

Response body:

```
{
    "thoughts": "",
    "data_points": ["thank you: James","goodbye:Ella"
    ]
}
```

I write Regular Expression:

```
"data_points":"(.+?)"
```

And script for BeanShell PostProcessor:

```
data_points = vars.get("data_points"); // get data from var data_points
 
f = new FileOutputStream("C://File/Book1.csv", true); //specify true if you want to overwrite file. Keep blank otherwise.
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(data_points); 

f.close();
```

I want to save the value of "data_points" and save only "thank you" and "goodbye" in the format: "thank you", "goodbye" for all the 2000 requests in a single csv file. Is there any way to do this?
I need help writing a regular expression. Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

1. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence it is not the best idea to use regular expressions for extracting data from there.
2. [Using Beanshell is kind of a performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), moreover if you run your script with > 1 user the `Book1.csv` will be [corrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

I would recommend the following approach:

- Instead of Regular Expression Extractor use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) configured like:

  [image]
- Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

  ```
   sample_variables=first,second
  ```

  see [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) user manual entry for more information
- Add [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to your Test Plan and configure it as follows:

  [image]

Comment: i tried your way but my csv file is empty

Comment: You need to restart JMeter in order to pick up the values from *user.properties* file, alternatively you can pass the sample_variables property via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like `jmeter -Jsample_variables=first,second -t your-test-plan.jmx` . More information: [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: How do I output all responses?